# What constant represents "never" for an NSTimeInterval?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimeinterval

`NSTimeInterval` is a `double`, thus it cannot take a `nil`, and 0 represents something that should happen immediately. Is there a constant that means "never"... or an astronomically huge value, or should I use -1?

Comment: `double` can take `inf` values. You can test with `isinf(x)` or `(x > DBL_MAX)`.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by s.bandara, use a very large number to treat a time interval as "infinite" or "never".

`DBL_MAX` is the largest value a double can hold.  This macro is declared in `float.h`:

```
#define DBL_MAX (9.999999999999999e999)
```

Comment: "Infinity" is not the same as `DBL_MAX`.

Comment: DBL_MAX is as close to infinity as a double value can get.  I've made this answer a community wiki based on the comment on the question.  You are free to edit it to improve the answer.

Comment: No, it's not, there's a special value in IEEE 754 floating point to represent infinity. I can't really see how to edit this without rewriting it completely.

Comment: So feel free to write your own answer if you feel that this answer is deficient.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, use `TimeInterval.infinity`. For example, in SwiftUI to conditionally enable a timeline view to update every second or never, use:

```swift
TimelineView(.periodic(from: start, by: isRunning ? 1 : .infinity))
```